# Create and start Azure devops release pipeline using C# and RestAPI

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, rest

I am trying to launch a release that deploys the database dacpac to another environment using C# and Azure Devops Rest API.

I have used the below code for executing the request, but I cannot get the pipeline start

```
    var definitionId = 4;
                var testvalue = "Changed value";
                string url = @"https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<Organisation>/<project>/_apis/release/releases?definitionId=4&api-version=5.1";
    string personalToken = "Test";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", personalToken);

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, " https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/<Organisation>/<project>/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1");
    
//requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definitionId\":" + definitionId + "};", Encoding.UTF8, //"application/json");
requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definitionId\":" + definitionId + ", \"variables\": { \"Test:\" { \"value\":" + testvalue +"}}};", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;  
    
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
                    // Parse the response body.
}
}
```

Tried with this code and unable to start the release..

I tried the same in the powershell and it works.

```
$VSTSAccoutName="Organisation"   
$teamProjectName="Project"
$ReleaseDefId="4"
 
$ReleaseMetadata = '{"definitionId": ' + $ReleaseDefId + ',
                    "variables": {
                          "Test": {
                          "value": "changed value test"
                        }
                          }
                        }';
 
 
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personaltoken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$Uri = 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/' + $VSTSAccoutName +'/'+ $teamProjectName + '/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0'
$ReleaseResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $ReleaseMetadata -Headers $header
Write-Host $ReleaseResponse
```

Am I missing something in the code above? Could you please suggest the right way of triggering the release ?

Comment: You did not put quotes around `testvalue` in the json. You might consider using a serializer rather than stringing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder I used serializer and also changed the api version to 5.0. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with  Crowcoder .

Tested with the same C# Code and I could reproduce the same issue.

To solve this issue, you need to change the parameters definition.

For example:

`var definitionId = "\"15\"";`

`var testvalue = "\"test123\" ";`

Here is the sample code, you could refer to it:

```
namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             var definitionId = "\"15\"";
            var testvalue = "\"test123\" ";
             string personalToken = "PAT";
            var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalToken}"));

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
             {
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

                 var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/organization/Project/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1");

                //requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definitionId\":" + definitionId + "};", Encoding.UTF8, //"application/json");
                //requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definitionId\":" + definitionId + "};", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definitionid\":" + definitionId + ", \"variables\": { \"test\" : { \"value\": " + testvalue + " }}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
                 {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the release pipeline could be triggered successfully.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I changed the definition and I also had to change the api version to 5.0. That solved my issue!